# Как правильно использовать phpQuery?

Tags: php

Помогите, а то уже голову сломал. Есть у меня, например, такой html:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <div class="block"></block>
    <div class="block"></block>
    <div class="block"></block>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Как мне с помощью phpQuery выбрать содержимое в дивах с классом `block`?

Comment: Так же, как и в jQuery:

    $document = pq('<html><head></head><body><div class="block"></block><div class="block"></block><div class="block"></block></body></html>');

а дальше [ответ][1] @MasterAlex.

  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/373001#373004

Comment: @VasyOk, я немного добавил, думаю, автору нужно именно содержимое блоков.

Answer (score 1):

```
$blocks = $document->find('div.block');
foreach($blocks as $value) {
    $result[] = pq($value)->html();
}
```

Попробуйте вот так. По идее, в `$rezult` лежит массив с содержимым дивов.

Comment: делаю после этого
`foreach ($blocks as $q){
    echo $q->html();
}`

и ничего не выводит((

Comment: Потому что в них ничего нет, ваш КЭП.

Comment: @Diefair, потому что нужно использовать 'pq', поподобие доллара у jQuery

Comment: @MasterAlex, и так, и этак будет работать. У него между `"<div class="block">"` и `"</block>"` ничего нет, добавит - сразу все появится.

Comment: @VasyOk, припустим, что есть. ))

Comment: @VasyOk, что-то меня смущает конструкция `'<div class="block"></block>'`, дивы ведь надо закрывать. :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, сделал 
`foreach ($blocks as $q){
    echo pq($q)->html();
}`
- тоже ничего не выводит.

Comment: сори, я затупил, все выводит. )

Comment: @MasterAlex, точняк :D

Comment: @Diefair, это работает:

   $document = pq('<html><head></head><body><div class="block">block 1</div><div class="block"><p>block 2</p></div><div class="block"><div>block 3</div></div></body></html>');